# Java Threads Object Lock

Tags: java, multithreading

According to my understanding, every object has a lock that can be hold by the current thread.

So, based on this example:

```
public class T1 {
    private final Object o = new Object();

    public  void m1() {
        synchronized(o) {
            //...wait some time
        }
    }
}
```

If I create something like:

```
    T1 subject1 = new T1();
    T1 subject2 = new T1();
    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            subject1.m1();
            subject2.m1();  
        }
    };

Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
t1.start();
```

There will be two locks, `subject1.o` and `subject2.o` (I tested they are different instances), which means both methods will run independently and at the same time, well, in my example one is executed and then, after it releases the lock, the next runs although subject1 and subject2 are different instances with different locks.

Why?

Comment: Both subject1 and subject1 are instances of T1 extends Object, therefore, if you apply lock on object by calling synchronize, they will process in order of lock acquiring...

Comment: But each instance contains its own lock, doesn't it?
So, why the behaviour looks like they share the same lock?

Comment: They extend same object on which both put right to lock. Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class. Therefore if subject1 acquired lock on Object, it won't allow others to access it( synchronize takes care of that ) until it finishes it's work.

Comment: Ok, both classes extend Object, but talking at instance level, both Object parent's class are also different. If you're talking at Class level, then any other instance of any other object would be locked as well.


The point here is why even with different instances of T1, they block each other given they have different lock object instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There will be two locks, `subject1.o` and `subject2.o` ..., which means both methods will run independently and at the same time.

No. The fact that there are two locks does *not* mean that two calls to the `m1` function will run independently and at the same time.  It only means that two calls *can* run at the same time.  But that can only happen if each of those two calls happens in a different thread.

What other answers here have already tried to tell you is, your code doesn't make the two calls from two different threads.  It makes both calls from *the same* thread.  You wrote this run() method:

```
public void run() {
    subject1.m1();
    subject2.m1();  
}
```

There's nothing special about a `run()` method.  *YOU* wrote it, and it will work exactly like any other method that you write:  The one that you wrote will first call `subject1.m1()`, and then when that returns, it will call `subject2.m1()`.

If you want to make those calls in parallel, then do what @Palamino or @snr showed you.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are running the two method sequentially in the same thread.  To execute them in parallel, you must run them in separate threads.

```
T1 subject1 = new T1();
T1 subject2 = new T1();
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        subject2.m1();  
    }
};
Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        subject2.m1();  
    }
};

Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: @Eduardo, the locks are not blocking each other in your example.  They are simply running the first method to completion before the second method begins executing.

Answer (score 1):

> There will be two locks, `subject1.o` and `subject2.o` (I tested they
>   are different instances), which means *both methods will run
>   independently* and at the same time

You say both methods will run independently though you have only one enclosing method to run both threads. Instead, both methods have to be within different `Runnable`s to be executed concurrently.

```
T1 subject1 = new T1();
T1 subject2 = new T1();
Runnable r1 = subject1::m1;
Runnable r2 = subject2::m1;
Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
t1.start();
t2.start();
```